# The last cell image is 'blank' when tableview is reloaded in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

I have a friend list showing in a UITableView. The data is pulled locally at first (via SQLLite DB), and in the background the modified friends are pulled via the web service. 
When the web service provides additional data and the tableview is updated to show this data, occasionally the last cell's UIImageView shows a 'blank' image. If the cell is regenerated within that same view (via scrolling), the image shows up proper. Also, once the view is reloaded (by going out and coming back again), the image shows up properly.

I'm using SDWebImage SDK to load and cache the image.

Code for the cell dequeue:

```
var cellFriend =  self.friendsData[indexPath.row]
    let imageBaseURL = NSURL(string:BaseUrl + cellFriend.image)
    cell.friendImage.setImageWithURL(imageBaseURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"place-holder-profile-pic@3x.png"))
        cell.friendImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendImage.frame.size.width/2
        cell.friendImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The data from the SQLLite is added to a friend modal and displayed into the cell using `indexpath.row` as the index.

What is it that I could be doing wrong? I've used similar code throughout the app and this issue doesn't come up anywhere.

UPDATED:

Below is the code that loads the model from the database.

```
for dict in friendSQLArray{
                var id:Int =  dict.objectForKey("id") as! Int!
                var email:String = dict.objectForKey("email") as! String!
                var fName:String = dict.objectForKey("first_name") as! String!
                var lName: String = dict.objectForKey("last_name") as! String!
                var firstChar:String = dict.objectForKey("fName") as! String!
                var localPersonaID:Int = dict.objectForKey("persona_id") as! Int!
                var personaName:String = dict.objectForKey("persona_name") as! String!
                var image:String = dict.objectForKey("photo") as! String!
                var status:String = dict.objectForKey("profile_status") as! String!
                var friendStatus:String = dict.objectForKey("status") as! String!
                var toUserID:Int = dict.objectForKey("to_user_id") as! Int!
                var userID:Int = dict.objectForKey("user_id") as! Int!
                var userName:String = dict.objectForKey("user_name") as! String!
                var userPersonaID:Int = dict.objectForKey("user_persona_id") as! Int!
                var userStatus:Int = dict.objectForKey("user_status") as! Int!
                var lastActionID:Int = dict.objectForKey("last_action_by_user_id") as! Int!
                var friend = FriendDBModel(id: id, userID: userID, userName: userName, fname: fName, lname: lName, email: email, status: status, image: image, firstChar: firstChar, personaID: localPersonaID, personaName: personaName, toUserID: toUserID, userPersonaID: userPersonaID, userStatus: userStatus, friendStatus: friendStatus, lastActionID:lastActionID)
                self.friendsData.append(friend)
            }
```

All the data is present and the image, when accessed through a browser is visible.

Comment: Could you add the code in which you populate self.friendsData? As El Captain said, you need to wait for the code to load, putting it through a block or having a Notification trigger a reloadData.

Comment: @EICaptain the image is already cached as it was loaded earlier before the tableview was reloaded. The image doesn't change, it just disappears when the last cell reloads. Also, I've waited for quite a while as I thought that could be the issue.

Comment: @gran_profaci the tableview.reload function is called in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {} method. updated the question with data load function.